# How to insert into html table's specific column

Tags: python, html, flask

I've `.csv` file and trying to display it using flask and html tables. I've already parsed csv file and passed it into flask html template file.

this is my html file

```html
<table class='content-table'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for firstname in firstnames %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ firstname }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}

        {% for lastname in lastnames %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ lastname }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

which results

[image: a busy cat]

I wanted to fill Last Name column with Doe. How can I do it?

Comment: Instead of two loops, in first table row itself give both names as separate table data.

Comment: Or send the csv to the client and have the client process it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should zip() the firstname and lastname when you rendering your tempalte.
like `name_details = zip(firstnames, lastnames)`. Then you can use it in single for loop

```
<table class='content-table'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for firstname, lastnames in name_details %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ firstname }}</td>
            <td>{{ lastnames }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```